# Server-side Audio Editor

Tags: iis, iis-7, audio, editor

I am looking for an audio editor that we can use server side (ASP + IIS)

We want users to be able to upload an audio file, and then offer a 10 second teaser clip to other users for download.

Ideally I would like our application to be able to specify Input and Output Filename, Start and End time (or Duration), and be able to fade-in and fade-out, and equalise the volume.

Maybe some audio editors have a batch edit facility, and it would just be a question of installing on the server?

All the keywords I have tried putting into Google have led me on a wild goose chase, hopefully someone can help me with suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try ffmpeg!

http://ffmpeg.org/

I've used it for all sorts of manipulations of video and audio.